# SearchView: Keyboard not show button Done

Tags: android, searchview

android 4.3.

here snippet:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SearchView.ActionBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_view_bg"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:theme="@style/SearchViewTheme"
        app:defaultQueryHint="@null"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/searchViewContainer"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/searchViewContainer"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/searchViewContainer"
        app:searchHintIcon="@null" />
```

I want when click on **SearchView** to show keyboard with **Done** button. So I set `android:imeOptions="actionDone"`. But it not help:

Here result:

[image: keyboard]

Comment: This settings not help. Show glass button.

Comment: you need to add the android:maxLines="1" and make it EditText instead of SearchView

Comment: @KingofMasses **android:singleLine="true"** is deprecated

Comment: use android:maxLines="1" instead of android:singleLine="true"

Comment: In my example I use  android:maxLines="1" but it not help

Comment: This help:  searchViewEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
        searchViewEditText.setSingleLine(true);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
searchview.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
searchview.setSingleLine(true);
```

Comment: Try with this answer. And singleLine is deprecated but still it works that matters

Comment: Actually i was about to give same answer but seen the same that's y i appreciated -> Keep coding and Keep helping

Comment: @BabulPatel enjoy codding

Answer (score 0):

The xml for SearchView:

```
android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
android:inputType="text"
```

This will show you the search icon.